# HAProxy is limiting number of connections on my server

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I am trying to test my web application hosted on RHC Openshift, and I need to be able to connect certain number of clients to the server. I have already set maxconn in haproxy.cfg, but I am still limited to 260 connections and I can't find out why is this happening.

While testing, first 260 clients join without a problem, but after that server reacts like it is not possible to join it anymore, and it takes about one minute to allow other clients to join.

I need to be able to connect all clients without having this waiting time.

Maybe there is some limit of free plan, I am using, which I don't know about?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using a small gear it's possible that you are running out of memory on it.  Are these websocket connections or???

Comment: I am using socket.io for client-server communication. I don't think this may be caused by lack of memory. After this one minute period ends, it is again possible to join the server, and application works just fine, even with all 260 clients still running. Only those who tried to join right after reaching the limit are refused.

Comment: Are you making the change to maxconn under both the _defaults_ and _global_ sections?

Comment: Yes, I am. I thought the problem could also be in some kind of "x per minute limit" setting. Like sessions limit or so. But still can't hit anything that would help.